# install gimp with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, gimp

I worked with gimp a while back when users had to install x11. I want to install it again for a project requiring image editing. I see there are a lot of enhancements to the installation process. It seems installing x11 is not required anymore. I am so used to brew everything. Is there a way to install gimp with homebrew?

Comment: `brew install gimp`?

Comment: `brew install Caskroom/cask/gimp`?

Comment: `brew install gimp`does not work. But `brew cask install gimp`does.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Install `Gimp`

```
brew install gimp
```

This will install `Gimp` via [Homebrew Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/) automatically.

2020 edit: "brew *cask* install" is no longer necessary; brew will automatically tap casks when appropriate.

Comment: FYI you don’t even need the first command; Homebrew will install Homebrew Cask for you when using `brew cask install` for the first time.

Comment: I believe the current way (or another) to do this is: `brew install Caskroom/cask/gimp`

Comment: `brew install Caskroom/cask/gimp` works for me after others failed. My os is macOS10.14.5

Answer (score 13):

I tried to install using @pat's answer. It did not work.
The solution provided by @Gianfranco is the only one that did work:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install Caskroom/cask/gimp
```

The result is:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask

==> Tapping caskroom/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Counting objects: 3730, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3706/3706), done.
remote: Total 3730 (delta 39), reused 588 (delta 20), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3730/3730), 1.26 MiB | 1.39 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (39/39), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Tapped 0 formulae (3,738 files, 4.0MB)
```

And:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/gimp 

==> brew cask install Caskroom/cask/gimp 
==> Downloading https://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.8/osx/gimp-2.8.22-x86_64.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask gimp
==> Installing Cask gimp
==> Moving App 'GIMP.app' to '/Applications/GIMP.app'.
  gimp was successfully installed!
```

Comment: I've found `brew tap caskroom/cask && brew cask install gimp` also works.